# nativeApiProvider.get(...).retrieveJsMessages is not a function

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-android

In my Meteor Cordova app, the following error was logged in production:

```
nativeApiProvider.get(...).retrieveJsMessages is not a function
http://localhost:12472/cordova.js at line 1017, col 40 in pollOnce
http://localhost:12472/cordova.js at line 1008, col 5 in pollOnceFromOnlineEvent
```

I couldn't find these lines in the cordova-android source code on GitHub. What could it mean, and how do I know if it hurt user experience?